# How to create a waterfall plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I wanted to visualize the bar graph in a additive way (waterfall plot, see below).

This is the data:

```
structure(list(Parameter = c("Driving", "Driver Behaviour", "Road Quality", 
                             "Passenger load", "Speed", "Topography", "climate", "total"), 
               Values = c(0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.24, 0.5, 0.8, 2.82)),
          row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
#          Parameter Values
# 1          Driving   0.80
# 2 Driver Behaviour   0.20
# 3     Road Quality   0.20
# 4   Passenger load   0.20
# 5            Speed   0.24
# 6       Topography   0.50
# 7          climate   0.80
# 8            total   2.82
```

This is the output im trying to produce. Is there any way i can do it in R?

[image]

Comment: I think the term is _waterfall plot_. See e.g. [here](https://www.stomperusa.com/2019/05/27/basic-waterfall-graphs-in-r/) and `plotrix::staircase.plot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still in need of some polishing but in principle your watefall chart can be achieved like so:

BTW: Because of rounding errors your data gives a total of 2.94 instead of 2.82.

```r
d <- structure(list(Parameter = c("Driving", "Driver Behaviour", "Road Quality", 
                             "Passenger load", "Speed", "Topography", "climate", "total"), 
               Values = c(0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.24, 0.5, 0.8, 2.82)),
          row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Prepare the dataset
d1 <- d %>%
  mutate(ymax = cumsum(Values),
         ymin = lag(ymax, default = 0),
         xmax = as.numeric(factor(Parameter, levels = Parameter)),
         xmin = lag(xmax, default = 0),
         x = (xmin + xmax) / 2, 
         y = (ymin + ymax) / 2,
         label = Values,
         label_color = "white",
         ) %>% 
  # Get the total right
  mutate(ymin = ifelse(Parameter == "total", 0, ymin),
         ymax = ifelse(Parameter == "total", Values, ymax),
         y = ifelse(Parameter %in% c("Driving", "total"), Values + .2, y),
         label = case_when(
           Parameter %in% c("Driving") ~ paste0("Best Case\n", Values),
           Parameter %in% c("total") ~ paste0("Worst Case\n", Values),
           TRUE ~ as.character(Values)),
         label_color = ifelse(Parameter %in% c("Driving", "total"), "black", "white"))

ggplot(d1, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
  geom_rect(fill = "#E40019") +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, color = label_color), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(.5, 7.5, 1), labels = d1$Parameter) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(white = "white", black = "black")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>